# Migrated to Visual Studio 2010 from 2008. VisualSVN server bindings disapper suddenly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visualsvn

Greetings,

I have a server hosting c# projects/ solutions using VisualSVN/TortoiseSVN as the source control.

I opened one of those solutions (VS2008/.Net3.5) using VS2010.
It took me to the conversion wizard and once i SUCCESSFULLY finished and came out of conversion wizard, i go ahead and build the solution.

It builds fine. However, the server bindings that were supposed to show up do not appear. The entire solution in VS2010 does not seem to be in source control. Also, when i go to VisualSVN tab on the menu all the options like Update, Commit, Show Log, etc are grayed out.

Please suggest if i need to reinstall VisualSVN or is there anything missing. Thanks a lot.

Scott.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to reinstall VisualSVN. You might also need to purchase a newer version -- only the most recent versions work with Dev10 (the 2.xx series), and it is not a free upgrade :(.